# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sample #1 (works as expected):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hanoichurch.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^hicvn.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hicvn.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^hicvn.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hicvn.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^hanoiworship.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hanoiworship.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^google
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/hanoichurch\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Sample #2 (does not work*):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nathanbrauer.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^nathanbrauer.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nathanjbrauer.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^google
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/nathanjbrauer\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

*Fails silently (visiting www.nathanbrauer.com simply loads the page and doesn't redirect to nathanjbrauer.com).

A million thanks!

=== Update ===

What I ended up doing was using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nathanjbrauer\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^google
RewriteRule ^ http://nathanjbrauer.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please pardon my shortness. I figure everyone and their mother sees .htaccess issues on here so I figured I'd keep it short for you :)

Comment: Also, visiting these sites to test yourself may not work because I just changed nameservers so it may take some time before the DNS has propagated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample1 code can also be refactored but I will only suggest fixes to your sample 2 code since this is not working for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nathanbrauer\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nathanjbrauer\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^google [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://nathanjbrauer.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This looks right, and I think it *should* work.  But for some reason, it's not.  It's on the exact same server as hanoichurch.com (which works) with the exact same environment (vhost was copied from hanoichurch.com).  Both .htaccess are chmod 644 chown root:root.  And it *is* reading the htaccess on nathanbrauer.com (if I enter gibberish, I get a 500 error).  I'm so confused on this.  What else should I check?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work? Are you NOT getting redirected to `http://nathanjbrauer.com/uri`? OR are you getting some internal server error? What is the original URL are you testing with?

Comment: It's now live at http://nathanbrauer.com and http://nathanjbrauer.com.  Sorry for not being clear: I'm not being redirected (no 500 error).  It just loads the site as if these rules didn't exist.

Comment: I also tried using this as the ONLY condition (to no avail): `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nathanjbrauer\.com$`. The current live version is using the one you posted.

Comment: sorry but do you have `RewriteEngine on` on top of your .htaccess file?

Comment: No, but it shouldn't be necessary... I just added it so I can say I did it (to no avail), though.

Comment: Its really weird. For testing can you just add this rule the end: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nathanjbrauer\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^foo/$ http://nathanjbrauer.com/ [R=301,L]` and then visit `http://www.nathanjbrauer.com/foo/`

Comment: Heh, @anubhava, It didn't work because you put ".org" instead of ".com" --- I *just* noticed that.

Comment: Holy crap. ***I too*** put ".org"! Wow... I really must have been tired!

Comment: Good catch, I'm glad that it eventually worked out for you :)